# Error getting real time offset by using "datetime"

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

My program is written in Python there is the need for time. I used this code:

```
import datetime
offset = datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=3))
time=str(datetime.datetime.now(offset))
```

On my PC, the program correctly displays the time with an offset of 3, but when you transfer the program to another computer, the time is displayed there as if hours=10.

Example: I have on the PC is displayed so:

```
2019-04-20 20:16:49.297578+03:00
```

On another PC:

```
2019-04-21 03:16:57.505614+03:00
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Did you check the local time on the other system?

Comment: Yes, there is a different time relative to my PC, but what date and time settings affect the Python?

Comment: does the other pc  have different timezone?

Comment: Yes it is with a different time zone.

Answer (score 0):

datetime.datetime.now will return the current local date and time, so if the timezone is different on the 2 PCs this is expected behaviour.  Did you want something different?

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer